# Retrofit 2.0 - Adding header does not work

Tags: android, retrofit2, http-status-code-400

I am developing an Android application in which I would like to call an API using `Retrofit`. The API requires authorization token in the header and I added the same as well.

Below are the code snippets

**RetrofitClient.kt**

```
object RetrofitClient {
    var apiInterface: APIInterface? = null
    val okHttpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .connectTimeout(300, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .writeTimeout(300, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .readTimeout(180, TimeUnit.SECONDS)

    @Synchronized
    fun getClient(context: Context): APIInterface {
        if (apiInterface == null) {
            if (SharedPreference.isAuthTokenExists(context))
                okHttpClient.addInterceptor(HeaderInterceptor(context))
            apiInterface =
                Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(context.resources.getString(R.string.base_url))
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .client(okHttpClient.build())
                    .build().create<APIInterface>(APIInterface::class.java)
        }
        return apiInterface as APIInterface
    }

 }
```

**HeaderInterceptor.kt**

```
class HeaderInterceptor(private val context: Context) : Interceptor {
    private val HEADER_TOKEN = "token"
    override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response = chain.run {
        proceed(
            request()
                .newBuilder()
                .addHeader(
                    HEADER_TOKEN, "Bearer " + SharedPreference.initialize(context).getString(
                        Extras.AUTH_TOKEN, ""
                    )
                ).build()

        )
    }
}
```

**APIInterface.kt**

```
interface APIInterface {

    @POST("dialtogo/otp/verification")
    fun submitOTP(@Body otpModel: OTPModel): Call<ResponseFormat.GenericResponse?>?

     }
```

**OTPRepository.kt**

```
class OTPRepository(private var ctx: Context) {

    fun submitOTP(otpModel: OTPModel) {
        val apiInterface: APIInterface = RetrofitClient.getClient(ctx)
        val call: Call<ResponseFormat.GenericResponse?>? = apiInterface
            .submitOTP(otpModel)
        call?.enqueue(object : Callback<ResponseFormat.GenericResponse?> {
            override fun onResponse(
                call: Call<ResponseFormat.GenericResponse?>?,
                response: Response<ResponseFormat.GenericResponse?>
            ) {
                if (response.isSuccessful)
                    (ctx as dial.to.go.utils.Response)
                        .onSuccessResponse(response.body() as ResponseFormat.GenericResponse)
                else
                    (ctx as dial.to.go.utils.Response)
                        .onErrorResponse(response.errorBody().toString())
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<ResponseFormat.GenericResponse?>?, t: Throwable?) {
                (ctx as dial.to.go.utils.Response)
                    .onFailure(t?.message)
            }
        })
    }
}
```

I am getting ***400 Bad request*** in the response.

I do not find any issues in the API calls I invoke without header. I mean, it is working fine if the `SharedPreference.isAuthTokenExists(context)` returns false. And, FYI, It is working fine in ***POSTMAN***.

Please anyone help me find out solution for this.

Comment: Try to log the request and analyze the trace and check if it contains header, you can do that using HttpLogginInterceptor dependency

Comment: @rajanks I did not use that dependency but I tried to debug the call.request() but I do not find any headers in it. I am not sure on how it is getting missed out ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution to the issue I have been facing for long hours.

I made a silly mistake in the key name of header. It should be `Authorization` but was keeping it as `token`.

Thanks a lot for everyone who tried to help me out.

Answer (score 0):

Im not overly familiar with Kotlin, however you are clearing the request and only sending the header.

`HeaderInterceptor.kt` In Java it would be:

```
Request request = original.newBuilder()
                        .addHeader(HEADER_TOKEN, "Bearer " + SharedPreference.initialize(context).getString(Extras.AUTH_TOKEN, "")
                        .method(original.method(), original.body())
                        .build();
return chain.proceed(request);
```

Comment: I have tried this too but getting the same error :-(

Comment: Add a `HttpLoggingInterceptor` and check the header.

`HttpLoggingInterceptor getHttpLoggingInterceptor() {
    HttpLoggingInterceptor httpLoggingInterceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
    httpLoggingInterceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.HEADERS);
    return httpLoggingInterceptor;`

And check the Body too. Edit your question and add the output

Comment: Actually I got the solution. I have updated my question recently.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is first time as token won't exist it will create `apiInterface` without `HeaderInterceptor`, then as it is `singleton`, it will keep using same client and won't add the header again, better option is despite of token exists/not just add the `HeaderInterceptor` always as it wont cause any problem

```
@Synchronized
    fun getClient(context: Context): APIInterface {
        if (apiInterface == null) { 
            //removed the check for exists
            okHttpClient.addInterceptor(HeaderInterceptor(context))
            apiInterface =
                Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(context.resources.getString(R.string.base_url))
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .client(okHttpClient.build())
                    .build().create<APIInterface>(APIInterface::class.java)
        }
        return apiInterface as APIInterface
    }
```

Change your `HeaderInterceptor` to below

```
class HeaderInterceptor(private val context: Context) : Interceptor {
    private val HEADER_TOKEN = "token"

    override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {
        val modRequest = chain.request().newBuilder()
        val tokenAvailable = SharedPreference.isAuthTokenExists(context)
        if(tokenAvailable){
            modRequest.addHeader(HEADER_TOKEN, "Bearer " + SharedPreference.initialize(context).getString(Extras.AUTH_TOKEN, "")
        }
        return chain.proceed(modRequest.build())
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually, I am not calling getClient directly but calling reinitializeAPIInterface .  fun reinitializeAPIInterface(context: Context): APIInterface {
        apiInterface = null
        return getClient(context)
    }  . To make it straight forward to the readers, I just have updated in SO.

Comment: I guess there is no necessity to add `HeaderInterceptor` only if `token` exists, basically it will send empty header value, so try creating single client without reinitialisation and verify it that works.

Comment: How to send the header without Interceptor ? How to get rid of sending empty header value ? Please help me out.

Comment: I have updated the answer, remove condition while building the client and add tokenExists in Interceptor before adding auth header , this way this will be triggered everytime

Comment: I have tried your solution and tried calling getClient directly instead of reinitializing but same error :-(

Comment: did you remove the `if (SharedPreference.isAuthTokenExists(context))` condition in getClient ?

Comment: yes I have removed and tried as you mentioned.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227527/discussion-between-rajan-ks-and-rakesh-l).

Comment: I am not finding you on chat.

Answer (score 0):

Add header manually without calling headerInterceptor class fuction,inside RetrofitClient.kt file

```
kHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();

httpClient.addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
    @Override
    public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
        Request request = chain.request().newBuilder().addHeader("parameter", "value").build();
        return chain.proceed(request);
    }
});
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).baseUrl(url).client(httpClient.build()).build();
```

Comment: Actually, I tried in this way at the beginning. As it didn't work , I just have updated in the way I have mentioned in my post. But, still getting the same error :-(